# Receiving Delegate Methods for iAd Banners iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, iad

In iOS 7, ADBannerView no longer needs to be created manually. Instead, they can be requested with a simple `self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;`

Now, I cannot set my View Controller as the banner delegate because there is no banner for me to access (to my knowledge).

I need to know when the banner is tapped and when that action is dismissed so I can properly pause/start my Sprite Kit game.

How am I supposed to have these delegate methods called so I can properly respond to the user's actions?

AFAIK, there is nothing in the [UIView Controller iAD Additions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iAd/Reference/UIViewController_iAd_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) that explains how to set the delegate for the banners.

Do I need to create the banners manually, or is there a way to achieve this while still using the newer API's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, if you want to use the delegate methods, you will need to set up your iAd Banner manually.  Even if you make your vc the delegate, by just using self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES, will not call the methods you need.  In my sprite kit game, I made all the banners manually so I could take care of pausing the game and going to the background.  Making them give you the control you are looking for.  Good luck.